# How do call a javascript function from its method name in string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, function

Does anybody know how to call a javascript function such as

```
function sampleCallback() {
      alert("hello");
}
```

from a string "sampleCallback()"?

I have a multidimensional array like so:

```
hintSlidesArray = [
                    [{ "element": "noelement" }, { "hintMessage": "Welcome"}, "callback": "sampleCallback" }],
                  ];
```

And would like to pass the callback string to it so that I can run it from where im reading the array.

Comment: You can call it with `eval("sampleCallback()")`

Comment: I've managed to use 

     window[callback]();

where callback is my method name.

This is the most recommended setting and Eval is not!

Answer (score 4):

Any global variables - including functions - are properties of the global object. In a browser environment this is `window`. So you can use the array subscript syntax to access the property you are looking for:

```
window[hintSlidesArray[0][2].callback]();
```

If you need to specify a value for `this`, you can use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
window[hintSlidesArray[0][2].callback].call(value_for_this);
```

However, you should really consider storing the function instead of its name in your object. If the function is already defined in the current scope (or the global scope) when creating the object, this is as easy as removing the quotes from the function name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method. For example:

```
hintSlidesArray[0][2].callback.call(this)
```

Comment: `hintSlidesArray[0][2].callback` is a string. It doesn't have a `call` or `apply` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the javascript function using window object:

```
var functionResult = window[myFunctionName];
```